# Aligning labels and sliders in Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

Still very new to iOS.

Here is what I have:

[image]

[image]

Here are the settings for the Root stack:

[image]

[image]

And here are the settings for the other stacks:

[image]

Edit: All other settings are set to their defaults.

I want the view to look something like this,

[image]

I've tried tweaking the stack views by changing their content hugging and compression resistance to no avail.

What are my options here?

I've been told that using multiple stack views is the best way to approach Auto Layout. So far, it has just been frustrating.

Comment: just center your label in slider vertically, rigth click on your label and drag to your slider, the option should appear

Comment: *"I've been told that using multiple stack views is the best way to approach Auto Layout."* You should distance yourself from whoever told you that. In *some* cases, multiple stack views can be very helpful. In other cases, absolutely not. Start by working through a few tutorials on auto-layout and *then* think about how constraints (and/or stack views) would best work with your design.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the constraints are making this problem.

Before you read my answer I would recommend to read some tutorials and at least it help ME a lot this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-auG-myu02Q 1:16:40

Unembed Root stackView from Editor -> unembed

and delete all the constraints and content hugging .Re-Stack again Red(label and slider) , Green(etc) and Blue(etc) with out any constraints. (No width and height) Just play with spacing for start between label and slider( keep spacing same for the three stacks.(you can put slider a standard width BUT keep it same at all the three Red, Green, Blue.

Then Stack [ Red , Green , Blue ] *** not view

---

### label --- slider

### label --- slider

### label --- slider

It will be Vertical and distribution : fill equally

Add spacing ,to look like the picture you have at the end of you answer.

Name it for example stackRGB.

Then stack stackRGB with view . And that will be vertical again and distribution fill equally. Add spacing, to make it look like the picture at the end of your answer

Then you can add constraints to keep it where you wanna have it on your screen.

[Here is a small picture to see what I am saying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqxka.png)

By following the numbers on the boxes you can see the steps of stacking

It's a bit difficult for start but when you get the idea then it's pretty easy.

I hope this will help.